# How to target a specific column in datagridview while exporting to pdf table with iTextsharp c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I have a code that I use for create a pdf table with iTextSharp populated from a datagridview.
[datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfip8.png)
[pdftable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jgLX.png)

In the Video Column there's a long link that I want to replace with an anchor because it's causing an increase of row height.

I find this code that add the anchor so instead of the link you see the text "video" and on click will open the link:

```
var videoCell = new PdfPCell();
                                    var c = new Chunk("Video");
                                    c.SetAnchor(Convert.ToString(cell.Value));
                                    videoCell.AddElement(c);
                                    pdfTable.AddCell(videoCell);
```

This works fine but it's applied to all the columns, so the result is this:
[resultwithanchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQHMt.png)

So I tried to add an if condition to determine what is the column but doesnt work in anyway.

How I can target the video column to add chunk anchor only to that?

Here the code that generate the pdf table and populate it from datagridview:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            sfd.FileName = "Output.pdf";
            bool fileError = false;
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(sfd.FileName);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        fileError = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("It wasn't possible to write the data to the disk." + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (!fileError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
                        pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
                        pdfTable.TotalWidth = 550f;
                        pdfTable.LockedWidth = true;
                        float[] widths = new float[] { 70f, 30f, 60f, 40f, 50f, 30f };
                        pdfTable.SetWidths(widths);
                        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                       
                        
                        

                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
                        {
                            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                            pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
                        }

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                        {
                            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                            {

                                // I tried everything here
                                if ( ......... == "Video")
                               
                                {
                                    var videoCell = new PdfPCell();
                                    var c = new Chunk("Video");
                                    c.SetAnchor(Convert.ToString(cell.Value));
                                    videoCell.AddElement(c);
                                pdfTable.AddCell(videoCell);
                               
                                    }
                                   else
                                  {

                                    
                                    pdfTable.AddCell(Convert.ToString(cell.Value));
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: if (cell.ColumnIndex == 5) { // video cell  } else { // not a video cell }

Comment: @JohnG Yes, it's working!! Thank you very much!!